# writing in a mysql table using POST & php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to register the e-mail entered in my form by users in my SQL table. but I'm not receiving any errors and the data are not saved either!

```
 <?php
 echo "I was here !!!";
if(!empty($_POST['mail']))
{
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mailing";
echo "I was here !!!";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = 'INSERT INTO contact VALUES ("","'.$_POST['mail'].'")';
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

  $conn->close();
}
?>
```

and my html code:

```
    <div class="form">
        <p>Rester notifié par toutes les nouveautés !</p>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" class="mainform">

            <div class="field"><input type="text" class="field"  name="mail"  /></div>
            <div class="submit"><input class="submit" type="button" value="Envoyer" /></div>    

           </form>      
    </div>
```

can you tell me what's the problem ?

Comment: What is currently your output?

Comment: Nothing ! I recieve no error and nothing is written in the table

Comment: is there any output from your script?

Comment: No there is not output

Comment: Do you have any records in log files, after performing such kind of action?

Comment: the problem was with the type of the button which had to be sumbit ! thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your button type .because if you want to submit the data by form then button type should be submit like that

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
```

Comment: i am glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a value for $_POST['mail']. Your condition didn't handle empty value for $_POST['mail']. If there is a value. Change your query

```
INSERT INTO contact(email) VALUES ("'.$_POST['mail'].'")
```

Try this. Since you only need to add an email. Hope it helps.